# unique_ptr custom storage type example?

Tags: c++11, unique-ptr

*Howard Hinnant* [explained](http://home.roadrunner.com/~hinnant/unique_ptr03.html) that `unique_ptr` can also use a **custom storage type**. He mentions as an example "*shared memory*".

He only gives the rough idea (which is fine for a quick intro). But can anyone complete his example for a *"custom storage type"* (be it shared memory or not)?

> To support placing `unique_ptr` into shared memory, the custom deleter can contain a **custom pointer type** (typically not a real pointer in shared memory applications). One simply places a *nested type* called *pointer* which emulates pointer behavior within your deleter, publicly accessible:

```
template <class T>
class MyDeleter
{
public:
    class pointer
    {
     public:
        friend bool operator==(pointer x, pointer y);
        friend bool operator!=(pointer x, pointer y);
        // ...
    };

    void operator()(pointer p);
};

void test()
{
    unique_ptr<int, MyDeleter<int> > p;
    MyDeleter<int>::pointer p2 = p.get();  // A custom pointer type used for storage
}
```

I suspect that `// ...` must be extended, and `test()` will probably do some additional things in a real "custom storage type" example.

Can someone tell me where he/she

- has actually already **used this customization**,
- and in that **context**,
- which what **customization code**, (at `//...` probably)
- and how **client code** uses it? (at `test()` probably)

Comment: There's unlikely to be many uses of this customization- given that it's a very new library feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be interested in [boost::offset_ptr](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost/interprocess/offset_ptr.html) which served as the motivating use case for this customization point in `unique_ptr`.  `offset_ptr` is a fully developed pointer type which could be installed into a custom deleter using a simple typedef.  Its use case is to put `unique_ptr` into shared memory.

Answer (score 2):

20.7.1.2/3 tells us

> The type unique_ptr<T, D>::pointer shall satisfy the requirements of NullablePointer (17.6.3.3).

According to 17.6.3.3, given a type `P`, these requirements are:

- `P` is *EqualityComparable*, *DefaultConstructible*, *CopyConstructible*,
  *CopyAssignable*, and *Destructible*
- Lvalues of `P` are *swappable*
- Value-initializing an object of type P produces the *null value* of the type, and the null value shall be equivalent only to itself
- An object of type `P` can be *contextually converted* to `bool`
- An object of type `P` can be initialized with and assigned `nullptr`, and this produces the null value
- An object of type `P` can be equality compared to `nullptr`, and the comparison is true if and only if the object has the null value
- None of the required operations may throw (but need no explicit `noexcept` or `throw()`)

Note specifically that `operator*` and `operator->` are not actually required. Also note that the builtin numeric types satisfy all the requirements except `nullptr` initialization/assignment.

For example, the following type should fulfill all the requirements:

```
class handle {
    int id;
  public:
    // default and nullptr constructors folded together
    handle(std::nullptr_t = nullptr) : id(0) { }

    explicit operator bool() { return l.id != 0; }

    friend bool operator ==(handle l, handle r) { return l.id == r.id; }
    friend bool operator !=(handle l, handle r) { return !(l == r); }

    // default copy ctor and operator= are fine

    // explicit nullptr assignment and comparison unneeded
    // because of implicit nullptr constructor

    // swappable requirement fulfilled by std::swap
}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that reference out to me, and for the example. You call that class `handle` -- therefore I could use that class by putting a `typdef handler pointer;` inside my *deleter*?

Comment: @towi - Yep. The class is supposed to resemble a wrapper for some sort of an opaque identifier used in many libraries, such as a Windows window handle or an OpenGL texture name.