# Should std::unique_ptr<void> be permitted

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, gcc, c++11, unique-ptr

This is a very simple question.  Consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

typedef std::unique_ptr<void> UniqueVoidPtr;

int main() {
    UniqueVoidPtr p(new int);
    return 0;
}
```

Compiling with cygwin (g++ 4.5.3) with the following command `g++ -std=c++0x -o prog file.cpp` works just fine.  However, compiling with the microsoft compiler (either VS 2010 or 2013) I get this error:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\INCLUDE\memory(2067) : error C2070: 'void': illegal sizeof operand
        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\INCLUDE\memory(2066) : while compiling class template member function 'void std::default_delete<_Ty>::operator ()(_Ty *) const'
        with
        [
            _Ty=void
        ]
        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\INCLUDE\type_traits(650) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::default_delete<_Ty>' being compiled
        with
        [
            _Ty=void
        ]
        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\INCLUDE\memory(2193) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::tr1::is_empty<_Ty>' being compiled
        with
        [
            _Ty=std::default_delete<void>
        ]
        foo1.cpp(7) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::unique_ptr<_Ty>' being compiled
        with
        [
            _Ty=void
        ]
```

Is this expected?  I'm writing a class where I wanted to have a unique pointer in the in the class.  While trying to work out the semantics of a move constructor for the class, I ran into this (I assume because I finally got my move constructor coded correctly: i.e. the other errors were fixed).

Comment: The default deleter in `std::unique_ptr` will call `delete` on the pointer, what do you expect to happen when you call delete on a `void*`?

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: Actually, the `default_delete` shall not call `delete` on a `void*` (see ixSci's answer). In addition, if it did call delete on a `void*`, then that would be UB (see Nevin's answer) in which case one could expect anything (not necessarilly an error).

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39288891/why-is-shared-ptrvoid-legal-while-unique-ptrvoid-is-ill-formed

Answer (score 24, accepted):

MSVC is right while GCC is wrong:

Standard(3.9/5):

> Incompletely-defined object types and the void types are incomplete types

Standard(20.7.1.1.2/4):

> If T is an incomplete type, the program is ill-formed

Comment: +1  Having this behavior be ill-formed instead of undefined, was an intentional design goal of `unique_ptr`.  Doing the same thing with the deprecated `auto_ptr` is undefined behavior.  The big differences is that ill-formed requires a diagnostic.  Undefined behavior can do anything, silently.  All this being said, `unique_ptr<void, custom_deleter>` is perfectly valid if your `custom_deleter` can handle the disposal of the `void*`.

Answer (score 23):

GCC actually has code to prevent it, but it didn't work until recently.

GCC's `unique_ptr` has a static assertion in `default_deleter::operator()` that should reject incomplete types:

```
    static_assert(sizeof(_Tp)>0,
                  "can't delete pointer to incomplete type");
```

However, as an extension GCC supports [`sizeof(void)`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Pointer-Arith.html#Pointer-Arith), so the assertion doesn't fail, and because it appears in a system header doesn't even give a warning (unless you use `-Wsystem-headers`).

I discovered this problem myself recently so to fix it I added this [10 days ago](http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/libstdc++/2013-10/msg00238.html):

```
    static_assert(!is_void<_Tp>::value,
                  "can't delete pointer to incomplete type");
```

So using the latest code on trunk your example fails to compile, as required by the standard.

Answer (score 8):

The question boils down to:

```
void* p = new int;
delete p;
```

Looking at n3797 5.3.5 Delete, I believe the `delete p` is undefined behavior because of mismatched types, so either compiler behavior is acceptable as the code is buggy.

Note:  this differs from `shared_ptr<void>`, as that uses type erasure to keep track of the original type of pointer passed in.

Comment: How shared_ptr differs? It uses type erasure for deleter, not a pointer type

Comment: @ixSci Look at an implementation? The deleter is templated on the original pointer type.

Comment: You're right by saying that your code snippet above yields UB. However, the `default_delete` should not call `delete` if the pointed type is incomplete otherwise the program is ill-formed (See ixSci's answer).

Answer (score 3):

Don't delete variables of `void *`。

If you want to work with something like Win32 Handles, please provide a custom deleter.

For example:

```
void HandleDeleter(HANDLE h)
{
    if (h) CloseHandle(h);
}

using UniHandle = unique_ptr<void, function<void(HANDLE)>>;
```

Then:

```
UniHandle ptr(..., HandleDeleter);
```