# std::unique_ptr<void> not accepted by gcc 4.9.0

Tags: c++, c++11

So `gcc 4.9.0` has [implemented](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19863509/192993) a `static_assert`ion that the type is not `void` to be correctly conforming to the standard. Which is great, all for standards conformance.

I have a variant type that stored the data under a `std::unique_ptr<void>` which now doesn't work. The easy fix is to just change it to a `std::shared_ptr<void>` and it compiles straight away. The better fix is to provide the deleter functor.

Is the following a safe way of fixing up the `unique_ptr`? Will this exhibit undefined behaviour with certain polymorphic types?

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
void Deleter(void * p) {
  delete reinterpret_cast<T*>(p);
}

int main() {
  const std::unique_ptr<void, void(*)(void*)> v(new int(199), Deleter<int>);
  std::cout << *reinterpret_cast<int*>(v.get()) << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier (in the long run anyway) and safer to use e.g. [Boost variant](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/variant.html) or [Boost any](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/any.html)?

Comment: why not use a proper variant type (like [`boost::variant`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/variant.html) or your own implementation) ? `void*` should be used as little as possible imo.

Comment: I do have my own variant type, that's what I've implemented. I would usually use a boost variant but my variant needs to be serializable. The type identification numbers that are derived form `MurmurHash3` and serialization functions are stripped. This makes the variant marshallable across processes/devices which is needed for my current use case.

Comment: @MattClarkson: using `reinterpret_cast` here is asking for troubles, I advise against using this with polymorphic types...

Comment: @MatthieuM., thanks, have changed to use `static_cast` as per Jonathan's advice.

Comment: @MattClarkson: I would point out that you are still not out of the woods, even with `static_cast`, the only valid transformation with `void*` is `T*` -> `void*` -> `T*`, if you cast back to anything else than the original type, you have trouble brewing.

Comment: I am casting back to the original type, guaranteed. The `Deleter` is instantiated with the same type as the incoming type.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Will this exhibit undefined behaviour with certain polymorphic types?

If you use `unique_ptr<void, void(*)(void*)>(new X(...), Deleter<X>)` that will be correct for any `X`, because the deleter uses the correct dynamic type of the object.

If you used `unique_ptr<void, void(*)(void*)>(new Derived(...), Deleter<Base>)` that will have undefined behaviour (for both polymorphic and non-polymorphic types) if `Base` does not have a virtual destructor, or if the `Base` sub-object is not at the same address as the `Derived` object that contains it.

However, you should use `static_cast` not `reinterpret_cast` in both places. You should prefer to use the weakest cast that will work for a given situation, `reinterpret_cast` is a sledgehammer.

To make the code less error-prone I would write a helper function so you only ever name the type once, something like:

```
template<typename T, typename... Args>
  std::unique_ptr<void, void(*)(void*)>
  make_unique_void_ptr(Args&&... args)
  {
    using Ptr = std::unique_ptr<void, void(*)(void*)>;
    return Ptr{ new T(std::forward<Args>(args)...), Deleter<T> };
  }
```

Comment: I am using your first example. Thanks for a great answer (as always).

Comment: I believe the second case is always Undefined Behavior, even if `Base` has a virtual destructor, simply because you cannot expect that `Derived*` -> `void*` -> `Base*` behave in a sane way since there is no guarantee that `(void*)derived == (void*)base` in general (even though with gcc if this is the first base it will work).

Comment: @MatthieuM. good point, but that doesn't mean it's _always_ UB, only when `(void*)derived != (void*)base`.

Comment: That UB could be avoided by doing `unique_ptr<void, void(*)(void*)>(static_cast<Base*>(new Derived(...)), Deleter<Base>)`, then it would only have UB if `~Base()` is non-virtual. But at that point you might as well just use `Deleter<Derived>` and avoid the problem entirely :)

Comment: @JonathanWakely: I believe that unless the conversion is `T* -> void* -> T*` the Standard regards the cycle as UB. In practice, it so happens that it only breaks if `(void*)derived != (void*)base`, but I would loathe relying on it as it's implementation dependent (ABI).

Comment: I don't think there's any UB if the addresses are the same. [expr.static.cast]/13: "If the original pointer value represents
the address A of a byte in memory and A satisfies the alignment requirement of T, then the resulting pointer value represents the same address as the original pointer value, that is, A. The result of any other such pointer conversion is unspecified."

Comment: Also [basic.compound]/3 "If an object of type `T` is located at an address `A`, a pointer of type _cv_ `T*` whose value is the
address `A` is said to point to that object, regardless of how the value was obtained."