# Making a QSharedPointer<void>

Tags: c++, qt, boost, smart-pointers, qsharedpointer

For historical reasons, I use `QSharedPointer<T>` in my software. At some points, we want to store `boost::shared_ptr<T>` that point to the same data, and which should keep alive the instances of the `QSharedPointer<T>`.

The common way to do this is to keep a copy of the other smart pointer within the deleter of `boost::shared_ptr<T>`. But to prevent the deleter from having different types for different `T`s, which would prevent easily getting a `QSharedPointer` back with `boost::get_deleter`, when the corrresponding `boost::shared_ptr` has been upcast, I wanted to store the original `QSharedPointer<T>` as a `QSharedPointer<void>` within the deleter, as opposed to using the `T`.

But I find that `QSharedPointer` is not up to the task, as it throws errors like "reference to void can't be done", when compiling its header.

Does anyone have an idea on how to make this work without exposing `T` into the deleter?

Comment: Could you please clarify this: `At some points, we want to store boost::shared_ptr<T> that point to the same data`? You mean you would like to have multiple ownership?

Comment: Just the idea of `QSharedPointer<void>` sounds wrong. What is the use of it? Looks like you need QVariant instead.

Comment: FWIW `unique_ptr<void>` is quite handy for RAII handles

Comment: It seems to me that the only way to do this is to have common ancestor for all `Ts`.

Comment: @sehe So, you want to do something in deleter?  How is `unique_ptr<void>` useful? You just wrote what states in the question.

Comment: @sehe BTW [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19840937/476681) tell it is illegal.

Comment: @BЈовић I guess I forgot to specify the custom deleter

Comment: Is there any reason why you would need to keep the QSharedPointer<>? Couldn't you just change them all to std::shared_ptr<> instead? As far as I know, the only reason to use a Qt pointer is for Widgets and those make use of QPointer instead. So I'm not too sure why that would be required.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot define QSharedPointer because void is not a proper type.  You could define QSharedPointer and then cast to and from T * and char * Like this:

```
class A {};

QSharedPointer<char> x((char *)new A);
A *ptr = (A *)x.data();
```

Ugly but it works.  You may also have to pass in a Deleter which correctly deletes the class to the constructor in order to get your class destructed correctly.

A better alternative would be to use a base class.