# Why is shared_ptr<void> legal, while unique_ptr<void> is ill-formed?

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

The question really fits in the title: I am curious to know what is the technical reason for this difference, but also the rationale ?

```
std::shared_ptr<void> sharedToVoid; // legal;
std::unique_ptr<void> uniqueToVoid; // ill-formed;
```

Answer (score 148, accepted):

It is because `std::shared_ptr` implements type-erasure, while `std::unique_ptr` does not.

---

Since `std::shared_ptr` implements type-erasure, it also supports *another* interesting property, viz. it does *not* need the type of the deleter *as template type argument* to the class template. Look at their declarations:

```
template<class T,class Deleter = std::default_delete<T> > 
class unique_ptr;
```

which has `Deleter` as type parameter, while

```
template<class T> 
class shared_ptr;
```

does not have it.

### So, why does `shared_ptr` implement type-erasure?

Well, it does so, because it has to support reference-counting, and  to support this, it has to allocate memory from heap and since it *has to* allocate memory anyway, it goes one step further and implements type-erasure — which needs heap allocation too. **So basically it is just being opportunistic!**

Because of type-erasure, `std::shared_ptr` is able to support two things:

- It can store objects of any type as `void*`, *yet it is still able to delete the objects on destruction properly **by correctly** invoking their destructor*.
- The type of deleter is not passed as type argument to the class template, which means a little bit freedom *without compromising type-safety*.

Alright. That is all about how `std::shared_ptr` works.

Now the question is, can `std::unique_ptr` store objects **as** `void*`? Well, the answer is, **yes** — provided you pass a suitable deleter as argument. Here is one such demonstration:

```
int main()
{
    auto deleter = [](void const * data ) {
        int const * p = static_cast<int const*>(data);
        std::cout << *p << " located at " << p <<  " is being deleted";
        delete p;
    };
    
    std::unique_ptr<void, decltype(deleter)> p(new int(959), deleter);
    
} //p will be deleted here, both p ;-)
```

Output ([online demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/24bbded3678aac53)):

```
959 located at 0x18aec20 is being deleted
```

---

You asked a very interesting question in the comment:

> In my case I will need a type erasing deleter, but it seems possible as well (at the cost of some heap allocation). Basically, does this mean there is actually a niche spot for a 3rd type of smart pointer: an exclusive ownership smart pointer with type erasure.

to which [@Steve Jessop](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13005/steve-jessop) suggested the following solution,

> I've never actually tried this, but maybe you could achieve that by using an appropriate `std::function` as the deleter type with `unique_ptr`? Supposing that actually works then you're done, exclusive ownership and a type-erased deleter.

Following this suggestion, I implemented this (though it does not make use of `std::function` as it does not seem necessary):

```
using unique_void_ptr = std::unique_ptr<void, void(*)(void const*)>;

template<typename T>
auto unique_void(T * ptr) -> unique_void_ptr
{
    return unique_void_ptr(ptr, [](void const * data) {
         T const * p = static_cast<T const*>(data);
         std::cout << "{" << *p << "} located at [" << p <<  "] is being deleted.\n";
         delete p;
    });
}

int main()
{
    auto p1 = unique_void(new int(959));
    auto p2 = unique_void(new double(595.5));
    auto p3 = unique_void(new std::string("Hello World"));
}
```

Output ([online demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9b4b823d95b50477)):

```
{Hello World} located at [0x2364c60] is being deleted.
{595.5} located at [0x2364c40] is being deleted.
{959} located at [0x2364c20] is being deleted.
```

To avoid the naked new, you can then:

```
template<typename T, typename... Args>
auto make_unique_void(Args&&... args)
{
     return unique_void(new T(std::forward<Args>(args)...));
}
```

in place of std::make_unique

Comment: Good answer, +1. But you might make it even better by explicitly mentioning that a `std::unique_ptr<void, D>` is still possible by providing a suitable `D`.

Comment: @Angrew: Nice one, you found the real underlying question that was not written in my question ;)

Comment: @Nawaz: Thank you. In my case I will need a type erasing deleter, but it seems possible as well (at the cost of some heap allocation). Basically, does this mean there is actually a niche spot for a 3rd type of smart pointer: an exclusive ownership smart pointer with type erasure ?

Comment: @AdN: I've never actually tried this, but maybe you could achieve that by using an appropriate `std::function` as the deleter type with `unique_ptr`? Supposing that actually works then you're done, exclusive ownership and a type-erased deleter.

Comment: Um... I don't see the need for `std::function` in the second part of your message or in any additional type erasure provided by `std::function`. Just pass a pointer to an instantiation or your `deleter<T>` as a deleter and that's all "type erasure" you will ever need in this example. No need to involve `std::function` at all. See: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3b2c04aadc638a02 We should probably as @Steve Jessop  about what he meant by his reference to `std::function`.

Comment: @AnT: You're right. `std::function` is unnecessary, as `T` is known inside the pointer having the same pointer-type for all `T`. Changed the example. Thanks for pointing out. :-)

Comment: @AnT `std::function` allows you to type erase stateful deleters

Answer (score 7):

One of the rationales is in one of the many use-cases of a `shared_ptr` - namely as a lifetime indicator or sentinel.

This was mentioned in the original boost documentation:

```
auto register_callback(std::function<void()> closure, std::shared_ptr<void> pv)
{
    auto closure_target = { closure, std::weak_ptr<void>(pv) };
    ...
    // store the target somewhere, and later....
}

void call_closure(closure_target target)
{
    // test whether target of the closure still exists
    auto lock = target.sentinel.lock();
    if (lock) {
        // if so, call the closure
        target.closure();
    }
}
```

Where `closure_target` is something like this:

```
struct closure_target {
    std::function<void()> closure;
    std::weak_ptr<void> sentinel;
};
```

The caller would register a callback something like this:

```
struct active_object : std::enable_shared_from_this<active_object>
{
    void start() {
      event_emitter_.register_callback([this] { this->on_callback(); }, 
                                       shared_from_this());
    }

    void on_callback()
    {
        // this is only ever called if we still exist 
    }
};
```

because `shared_ptr<X>` is always convertible to `shared_ptr<void>`, the event_emitter can now be blissfully unaware of the type of object it is calling back into.

This arrangement releases subscribers to the event emitter of the obligation of handling crossing cases (what if the callback in on a queue, waiting to be actioned while active_object goes away?), and also means that there is no need to synchronise unsubscription. `weak_ptr<void>::lock` is a synchronised operation.