# Can a function return multiple values of varying types?

Tags: c++, function, return-type, multiple-return-values

It thought it would be interesting to return multiple values (with different types!) from a C++ function call.

So I've looked around to maybe found some example code but unfortunately I could not find anything matching to this topic.

I'd like a function like ...

```
int myCoolFunction(int myParam1) {
    return 93923;
}
```

to work on different types to return multiple different types of values like

```
?whatever? myCoolFunction(int myParam1) {
    return { 5, "nice weather", 5.5, myCoolMat }
}
```

**So is something like this possible using C++**
*(My idea was to use a special AnyType-vector but I could not find example code therefore)* **or do I have to stay on these type of call?** *(see below)*

```
void myCoolFunction(cv::Mat &myMat, string &str){
   // change myMat
   // change str
}
```

**Note**: So the order and the count of the returned element will be the same every time - > The set stays identical (like `1.:double, 2.:int` in every case)

Comment: Check out Templates in C++ (Helpful link maybe : https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_templates.htm )

Comment: you can't do it in a normal way in c++, not in a total generic way, only to create a struct that except this kind of parameters.

Comment: Can I interest you in c++17's std::any?

Comment: Do you want your function to always return the same set of types or do you want your function to return different types depending on the input?

Comment: Your example looks like returning a `struct`, which you can do.

Comment: Yes the set will stay the same so like `{double, int, string, Mat}` in every case to maybe get the `double value by result[0]`,  `int value by result[1]` and so on @Holt

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to return multiple values, you can return an instance of a class wrapping the different values.

If you do not care about losing semantics, you can return a [`std::tuple`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple)<sup>1</sup>:

```
auto myCoolFunction(int myParam1) {
    return std::make_tuple(5, "nice weather", 5.5, myCoolMat);        
}
```

If you want to force the types (e.g., have a `std::string` instead of a `const char *`):

```
std::tuple<int, std::string, double, cv::Mat> myCoolFunction(int myParam1) {
    return {5, "nice weather", 5.5, myCoolMat};
}
```

In both cases, you can access the values using [`std::get`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/get):

```
auto tup = myCoolFunction(3);
std::get<0>(tup); // return the first value
std::get<1>(tup); // return "nice weather"
```

<sub><sup>1</sup> If you have a C++17 compliant compiler, you can make use of [template argument deduction](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction) and simply return `std::tuple{5, "nice weather", 5.5, myCoolMat}`.</sub>

Comment: And `auto`/`std::tuple{...}` for C++17.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, a function can return multiple types of different values, within an  [`std::tuple`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple), available in the standard library since C++11:

```
#include <tuple>

std::tuple<int, std::string, double, cv::Mat>
myCoolFunction(int myParam1) {
    return { 5, "nice weather", 5.5, myCoolMat }
}
```

If you're allowed to use C++14 code, you don't even have to declare the type:

```
#include <tuple>

auto myCoolFunction(int myParam1) {
     return std::make_tuple(5, "nice weather", 5.5, myCoolMat);
}
```

and [here is proof both of these versions compile](https://godbolt.org/g/Aq2nt3) (sans the `cv::Mat` - I don't think GodBolt has that available).

**Notes:**

- If you use `std::make_tuple`, the types might not be exactly what you expect. For example, in this case you'll get a `char *` although when defining the tuple explicitly you could force it to be `std::string` like I have above. This is usually not a problem.
- If some of the data is large, you might try to `std::move` it, to avoid copying the whole thing, e.g. passing `std::move(myCoolMat)`.

Comment: Note that the two codes are not equivalent - In the second case, the returned type is `std::tuple<int, const char *, double>`.

Comment: @Holt: Yes, that's actually worth mentioning explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

You can return a structure or use std::tuple.

Using struct, you can do:

```
myStruct create_a_struct() {
  return {20, std::string("baz"), 1.2f};
}
```

And with std::tuple

```
std::tuple<int, std::string, float> create_a_tuple() {
  return {20, std::string("baz"), 1.2f};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

(Answer for amusement really and to demonstrate the power of C++ rather than anything else.)

One way, which is really rather evil since you burden the call site with unpicking the contents is to use

`std::shared_ptr<void>`

as the return type. This is allowed since `std::shared_ptr` supports *type erasure*. (Unfortunately, `std::unique_ptr` doesn't so you have to rule that out.)

Clearly though, in the function, you'll need to use `std::make_shared` or similar.

Reference: [Why is shared_ptr<void> legal, while unique_ptr<void> is ill-formed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39288891/why-is-shared-ptrvoid-legal-while-unique-ptrvoid-is-ill-formed)

Answer (score -4):

Returning a std::vector of std::variant, where std::variant is template parameterized to your selection of types. If any type is actually possible, I'm not sure why you're doing that with structures and not simply writing to the memory space; not having a deterministic concept of the objects and types in the structure has low value.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.