# Handling data on wire using unique_ptr

Tags: c++11, pointers, unique

When receiving data on wire and sending it to upper applications, normally, in C style, we have a struct for example with a void*:

```
struct SData{
//... len, size, version, msg type, ...
void* payload;
}
```

Later in the code, after error checking and mallocating, ..., we can do something as:

```
if(msgType == type1){
    struct SType1* ptr = (struct SType1*) SData->payload;
}
```

In C++, an attempt to use unique_ptr fails in the following snippet:

```
struct SData{
// .. len, size, version, msg type, ...
std::unique_ptr<void> payload;
}
```

But as you know, this will cause:

```
error: static assertion failed: can't delete pointer to incomplete type
```

Is there a way to use smart pointers to handle this?

One solution I found is here: 
[Should std::unique_ptr<void> be permitted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19840937/should-stdunique-ptrvoid-be-permitted)

Which requires creating a custom deleter:

```
void HandleDeleter(HANDLE h)
{
    if (h) CloseHandle(h);
}
```

using

```
UniHandle = unique_ptr<void, function<void(HANDLE)>>;
```

This will require significantly more additional code (compared to the simple unsafe C Style), since for each type of payload there has to be some logic added.

Answer (score 1):

> This will require significantly more additional code (compared to the simple unsafe C Style), since for each type of payload there has to be some logic added.

The additional complexity is only calling the added destructors. You could use a function pointer instead of `std::function` since no closure state should ever be used.

If you don't want destructors, but only to add RAII to the C idiom, then use a custom deleter which simply does `operator delete` or `std::free`.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more on the "since no closure state should ever be used?"

Comment: @Makketronix `std::function` is a function pointer plus some encapsulated state — variables or stored arguments. Deleters seldom need more than the object being deleted.