# Repeat UV for multiple cubes in one vertex buffer object (VBO)?

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw, voxel

I am making a little voxel engine using a chunk system (like in Minecraft). I decided to make 1 VBO per chunk, so the VBO contain multiple cubes that will use different textures.

I actually have the UV of a cube and i would like to use it on all cubes in a VBO so the texture will wrap all cubes the same way if the cubes were in separated VBOs.

Here is what I'm actually getting:

[image: actual result]

How to tell OpenGL to do the same thing as the first cube on all cubes?

EDIT:
here are my shaders:
vertex shader
    #version 400

```
layout(location = 0) in vec3 vertexPosition_modelspace;
layout(location = 1) in vec2 vertexUV;

out vec2 UV;

uniform mat4 MVP;

void main() {
    gl_Position = MVP * vec4(vertexPosition_modelspace, 1);
    UV = vertexUV;
}
```

fragment shader

```
#version 400

in vec2 UV;

out vec3 color;

uniform sampler2D textureSampler;

void main(){
  color = texture(textureSampler, UV).rgb;
}
```

my glfw loop:

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
glUseProgram(programID);
glUniformMatrix4fv(MatrixID, 1, GL_FALSE, &chunkHandler.player.mvp[0][0]);

glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, grass);
glUniform1i(textureID, 0);

glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, chunkHandler.loaded_chunks[0]->vboID);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void*)0);

glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, tboID);
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void*)0);

glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, chunkHandler.loaded_chunks[0]->nbVertices);

glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
glDisableVertexAttribArray(1);

glfwSwapBuffers(window);
glfwPollEvents();
```

tboID: tbo is for texture buffer object

how i create the TBO:

```
glGenBuffers(1, &tboID);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, tboID);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 36 * 2 * sizeof(float), uvcube, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

Comment: It's not really clear. You want to have 1 unique texture for your VBO (applied to all cubes in the VBO) or 1 texture per cube in the VBO ?

Comment: 1 unique texture for the VBO applied to all cubes in the VBO. (Multiple textures is another problem i don't need help for it)

Comment: Not part of the question, but I would consider instancing if you are displaying a lot of cubes.

Comment: Also, would `glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);` work?

Comment: I don't understand your problem then. When you store your vertex in the VBO, you are storing the UV coordinate for the texture, for each vertex, right ? You have also set the texture unit correctly (from your screenshot), so it's just a matter of calling the texture2D call in your shader.

Comment: You think the problem is only in shaders ? i'll edit my question with my current shaders and my loop

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot no it's not working, i already tried

Comment: I don't get it. As far as i understand, there are 4 cubes in the image. There is 1 shader program and 1 texture, isn't it. So if the grass texture is bound it should be wrapped on each cube. What about `tboID`? Is the array buffer  `tboID` (for the texture coordinates) valid for all 4 cubes?

Comment: @Rabbid76 yes there are 4 cubes on this image, all cubes are in 1 VBO, there is 1 shader and 1 texture, but the texture only wrap 1 cube (on all it's sides, also masked sides) but i don't know how to make it wrap all cubes 1 by 1, staying with 1 VBO

Comment: @Shirakawa42 You don't need to do anything special, do the same for all 4 cubes. I guess that `tboID` is only valide for the 1st cube. Do you delete it somewhere? Is the variable `tboID` not set for the 2nd, 3rd and 4th cube?

Comment: @Rabbid76 that's what i'm looking for, i create the tbo just before entering the loop and i never delete it, but i don't know why it's not repeating the tbo on all cubes

Comment: @Rabbid76 i added how i create the TBO but i don't know what to add to code :/

Comment: @Shirakawa42 Try the following; add `glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);` right **after** `glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, tboID);` `glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void*)0);`

Comment: @Rabbid76 not working :/

Comment: @Shirakawa42 I'm out of ideas. But read [OpenGL object in C++ RAII class no longer works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46839586/opengl-object-in-c-raii-class-no-longer-works)

Answer (score 0):

While not a complete answer, I can help in debugging.
It seems to me that the texture coordinate are wrong (you don't provide the code for filling them).

In your fragment shader, I would output the U and V coordinate as colors:

```
#version 400

in vec2 UV;

out vec3 color;

uniform sampler2D textureSampler;

void main(){
  color = vec3(UV.u, UV.v, 0);
}
```

If the coordinates are correct, you should have a gradient on each cube face (each cube vertex will be colored based on its UV, so a (0,0) vertex is black and (0,1) is green and so on). 
If it's not the case, try to fix the texture value until you can see them correctly.

*This looks suspicious to me: `glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void*)0);`*

Comment: texture coordinates are good, actually all the sides of the textured cube are textured, also the masked sides. And when i am displaying only one cube it looks great

Comment: Did you get the gradient cubes ? Because if your texture coordinates are all 0 (or 1) (except for the bottom left cube), you'd get a uniform color for all other cubes. Please provide a dump of uvcube array. The size of the array is strange, you should have 18 vertex for 4 adjacent cubes (if sharing vertices) or 32 if independant and not 36. Make sure it's matching the number of vertices in the VBO's

Comment: Also, it'd be a better idea to associate the position and texture coordinate in a single object (store `x,y,z,u,v` per vertex, and use the 5th parameter to give the stride to the u,v pair). That way you can't mix the number of vertices, you've a single buffer to upload, and you don't need many fancy enabling disabling sequence.