# No texture if multiple textures in modern opengl

Tags: c++, opengl, stb-image

I'm using C++ and OpenGL 4.6 with SDL2 and glew.
I have a class Texture:

```
#include "stb_image/stb_image.h"
class Texture {
private:
    unsigned int m_RendererID;
    std::string m_FilePath;
    unsigned char *m_LocalBuffer;
    int m_Width, m_Height, m_BPP;
public:
    Texture(const std::string &path);
    ~Texture();

    void Bind(unsigned int slot = 0) const;
    void Unbind() const;

    inline int GetWidth() const { return m_Width; }
    inline int GetHeight() const { return m_Height; }
    inline int GetID() const { return m_RendererID; }
};

Texture::Texture(const std::string &path) 
    : m_RendererID(0), m_FilePath(path), m_LocalBuffer(nullptr), m_Width(0), m_Height(0), m_BPP(0) 
{
    stbi_set_flip_vertically_on_load(1); //Flip vertically because OpenGL renders texture in the opposite way
    m_LocalBuffer = stbi_load(path.c_str(), &m_Width, &m_Height, &m_BPP, 4);

    GLCall(glGenTextures(1, &m_RendererID));
    GLCall(glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_RendererID));

    GLCall(glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR));
    GLCall(glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR));
    GLCall(glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE));
    GLCall(glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP));

    GLCall(glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA8, m_Width, m_Height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, m_LocalBuffer));
    GLCall(glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0));

    if (m_LocalBuffer) {
        stbi_image_free(m_LocalBuffer);
    }
}

Texture::~Texture() {
    GLCall(glDeleteTextures(1, &m_RendererID));
}

void Texture::Bind(unsigned int slot) const {
    GLCall(glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0 + slot));
    GLCall(glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_RendererID));
}

void Texture::Unbind() const {
    GLCall(glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0));
}
```

If I create one texture the texture shows:

```
Texture texture("ship.png");
texture.Bind(0);
shader.Bind();
va.Bind();
ib.Bind();
shader.SetUniform1i("u_Texture", 0);
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, ib.GetCount(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, nullptr);
```

But if I create two textures I get only black screen:

```
Texture texture("ship.png");
texture.Bind(0);
Texture texture2("ship2.png");
texture2.Bind(1);
shader.Bind();
va.Bind();
ib.Bind();
shader.SetUniform1i("u_Texture", 0);
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, ib.GetCount(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, nullptr);
```

This should work. I was searching on the internet for 2 hours and I can't seem to find the reason as to why this won't work. Could you guys help me out?

Comment: Try to bind both textures _after_ both are created.

Comment: @tohomas: There's an unrelated bug in your code. See [OpenGL object in C++ RAII class no longer works](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46839586/734069) for details. Also, `m_FilePath` and `m_LocalBuffer` are only used by the constructor. Why do you keep them around as members?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end of the following lines of code

> ```
>  Texture texture("ship.png");
>  texture.Bind(0);
>  Texture texture2("ship2.png");
>  texture2.Bind(1);
> ```

the 2nd texture object (*"ship2.png"*) is bound to texture unit 1, but to texture unit 0 the default texture object (0) is bound.

Note when `Texture texture("ship.png");` is called then the texture object is created and bound to the current texture unit, after that the default texture object (0) is bound to the current texture unit:

> ```
>  Texture::Texture(const std::string &path) {
>
>      GLCall(glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_RendererID));
>
>      // [...]
>
>      GLCall(glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0));
>  }
> ```

Note, what you call *"unbind"*, doesn't unbind anything. `glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0)` binds the default texture object (0) to the texture unit which is currently active. There is no necessity to do that.

---

Simply change the order of the instructions to solve your issue. Create and load the texture objects first. Then bind the texture objects to the texture units:

```cpp
Texture texture("ship.png");
Texture texture2("ship2.png");

texture.Bind(0);
texture2.Bind(1);

shader.Bind();
va.Bind();
ib.Bind();
shader.SetUniform1i("u_Texture", 0);
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, ib.GetCount(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, nullptr);
```

---

As an alternative you can avoid to use the texture unit 0. Use the texture unit 0 for creating the texture object only:

```cpp
Texture::Texture(const std::string &path, unsigned int slot) {

    GLCall(glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0));

    // [...]
}
```

```cpp
Texture texture("ship.png");
texture.Bind(1);                     // <--- 1
Texture texture2("ship2.png");
texture2.Bind(2);                    // <--- 2
shader.Bind();
va.Bind();
ib.Bind();
shader.SetUniform1i("u_Texture", 1); // <--- 1
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, ib.GetCount(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, nullptr);
```

---

Or add a parameter for the texture unit to the constructor of the class `Texture`:

```cpp
Texture::Texture(const std::string &path, unsigned int slot) {

    GLCall(glGenTextures(1, &m_RendererID));

    GLCall(glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0 + slot));
    GLCall(glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_RendererID));

    // [...]

    // GLCall(glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0)); <--- delete
}
```

```cpp
Texture texture("ship.png", 0);
Texture texture2("ship2.png", 1);
```

Comment: First two methods didn't work, but the last one worked.

Comment: @Tohomas No, all 3 methods work, if you do it right!

Comment: Ok I tried again and the second one works too(I didn't see the updated version). I can't seem to get the first method to work.