# OpenGl, glUseProgram() returns GL_INVALID_VALUE even the shader's ID is right

Tags: c++, opengl, glew

I am trying to create model loader in OpenGl/GLEW/GLFW using ASSIMP library. My problem is that I get an `GL_INVALID_VALUE` error on `glUseProgram()` on **second** iteration of the main loop *(I have set up the macro, named* `GLCall` *that breaks the debugging whenever* `glGetError`  *returs something)*.

Here's some code the make context clearer:

Code in main loop that draws a model, runs well first time, after `model.Draw()` second time I get an error

```
model_shader.Bind();

glm::mat4 View = inputCompute(deltaTime, window);
glm::mat4 Projection = glm::perspective(glm::radians(45.0f), (float)CONFIG::WINDOW_WIDTH / (float)CONFIG::WINDOW_HEIGHT, 0.1f, 100.0f);
glm::mat4 Model = glm::translate(glm::mat4(1.0f), lampPosition) * glm::translate(glm::mat4(1.0f), transVectorControl(deltaTime, window)) * glm::scale(glm::mat4(1.0f), glm::vec3(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f));
glm::mat4 mvp = Projection * View * Model;
model_shader.SetUniformMat4f("u_MVP", mvp);
model.Draw(model_shader);
model_shader.Unbind();
```

So I figured the function `model.Draw()`  must do something to the shader's id but here it is and it actually only reads the shader's id.

Here's `model.Draw()` function (it is a member of the `Mesh` class):

```
void Mesh::Draw(Shader shader)
{
// bind appropriate textures
    unsigned int diffuseNr = 1;
    unsigned int specularNr = 1;
    unsigned int normalNr = 1;
    unsigned int heightNr = 1;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < textures.size(); i++)
    {
        GLCall(glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0 + i)); // active proper texture unit before binding
        // retrieve texture number (the N in diffuse_textureN)
        std::string number;
        std::string name = textures[i].type;
        if (name == "texture_diffuse")
            number = std::to_string(diffuseNr++);
        else if (name == "texture_specular")
            number = std::to_string(specularNr++); // transfer unsigned int to stream
        else if (name == "texture_normal")
            number = std::to_string(normalNr++); // transfer unsigned int to stream
        else if (name == "texture_height")
            number = std::to_string(heightNr++); // transfer unsigned int to stream

                                                 // now set the sampler to the correct texture unit
        GLCall(glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(shader.getID(), (name + number).c_str()), i));
        // and finally bind the texture
        GLCall(glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[i].id));
    }

    // draw mesh
    GLCall(glBindVertexArray(VAO));
    GLCall(glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, indices.size(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0));
    GLCall(glBindVertexArray(0));

    // always good practice to set everything back to defaults once configured.
    GLCall(glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0));
}
```

`shader.getID()` simply returns ID that is held in `Shader` class a private member.

As You can see shader's id is only being read, but not written.
I actually checked and second time ID remains the same as before `model.Draw()` was executed. The model actually gets drawn right before second iteration of the main loop. 
I tried removing error checking from `glUseProgram()` but then the `glUniform()` gives me error about no shader being bind.

Comment: I bet that the shader program object is destroyed in the destructor of  the class `Shader`. Use a reference parameter in `Draw`: `void Mesh::Draw(Shader &shader)` and read [OpenGL object in C++ RAII class no longer works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46839586/opengl-object-in-c-raii-class-no-longer-works)

Comment: @Rabbid76 I thought about it, but shader is instantieted in `int main()` so it is 'alive' until program exits. I did what you suggested and it still doesnt work

Comment: @Rabbid76 well Forgive my incomeptence sicne I still am a beginner, as I said, passing it by refrence didn't do a job.

Comment: @Rabbid76 but its all inrelevant since I bind shader in `int main()` and `mes.Draw()` only takes shader as a parameter to use its Id

Comment: It is completely irrelevant where the object is instanced, if it is passed by value then a copy of the object is constructed and destructed.

Comment: @Rabbid76, well So I fixed it by just passing the ID and not the whole shader, guess I shouldnt have blindly follow tutorials. Thanks for help!

Comment: @Rabbid76 I must admit you being right, I forgot that I call the `Mesh.Draw()` through another class and I had to switch all parameters to passing by refrence. Please forgive me being so light tempered. Thanks for helping me resolving the issue!

Answer (score 0):

A fix to this problem turned out quite simple, I just passed the ID instead of whole shader and it worked just fine. Also passing Shader by refrence resolved the issue.